# Adding Facebook app stopped working - getsession stopped working

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, oauth-2.0

I've have this simple iframe app using the php sdk. Suddenly, a new Facebook user cannot add it as an application. 
 I tried the new php SDK example but without success.

a. I'm including the code here so, if someone can give me pointers.

b. I'm willing to hire someone to make the the correction.

```
<?php

require 'facebook.php';

$test = 0;

if ($test == 1) {
   $appCanvasPage = 'https://apps.facebook.com/myapptest/';
   $app_id = "";
   $app_secret = "";
}
else {
   $appCanvasPage = 'https://apps.facebook.com/myapp/';
   $app_id = "";
   $app_secret = "";
}



$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId' => $app_id,
'secret' => $app_secret,
'cookie' => true
));


$session = $facebook->GetSession();

$loggedin = 0;

echo "status ".$_GET['installed'];
echo "\n\nsession=".$session;

if (!empty($session)) {

   //echo "status ".$_GET['installed'];

   if ($_GET['installed'] == '1') {
      header("Location: $appCanvasPage");
   }

   try {
      $uid = $facebook->getUser();
      $user = $facebook->api('/me');

   }  catch (Exception $e) {}

   if (!empty($user)) {
      $loggedin = 1;
      echo "Hello ".$user['first_name'];
   }
   else {
      $url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
      echo "<a href='".$url."'> Click Here </a> to Add the Facebook MyApp\n";
   }
}
else {
   //$url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();

   $url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('canvas' => 1,
                                       'fbconnect' => 0,
                                       'req_perms' => '',
                                       'next' => $appCanvasPage.'index.php',
                                       'cancel_url' => $appCanvasPage ));  

   echo $url;
   echo "<a href='".$url."'> Click Here </a> to Add the Facebook MyApp\n";
}


?>

<?php if ($loggedin == 1) { ?>
<pre>
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
   <head>

   <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript1.2" src="https://www.myappwebsite.com/myapp.js"></script>

   <style type="text/css">
   body {
   width:530px;
   height:600px
   margin:0; padding:0; border:0;
   font: bold 14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   }
   </style>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;
   charset=iso-8859-1" />
   </head>
   <body>
   <div id="container">
   <center>
   <table border=0 width="90%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
   <tr><td align="left">
   <center>
   <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" width="80%" class="headers2">
   <tr>
      <td valign="top" align="center">

      <h2> MY APP WILL GO HERE </h2>

      </td>
   </tr>
   </table>
   </center>
   </form>


   </center>
   </div>
   </body>
   </html>
<?php } else { ?>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I think you just need to login via user not the session, read this https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/503

Comment: Thank-you. I've started making these changes but now I'm stuck on how to get 
the request permissions screen to show up.

I'm at this point where I capture the login url.

<a href='https://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=<api_key>&cancel_url=https%3A%2F%2Fapps.facebook.com%2Fmyapp%2F&display=page&fbconnect=0&next=https%3A%2F%2Fapps.facebook.com%2Fmyapp%2Findex.php&return_session=1&session_version=3&v=1.0&canvas=1&req_perms='> Click Here </a>&nbsp; to Add the My App


When I click on the link nothing happens but when I copy and paste the url into
the address bar it does work.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This really looks like you must update Facebook php-sdk to the newest version.
See post on developers blog: [Upgrade to PHP SDK v3.0.0](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/503)

Also you may want to read posts:

[Breaking Change: JavaScript SDK to oauth:true on December 13th](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/614/) (this is probably then your app stopped working, as many others, see comments to that post)

[Updated JavaScript SDK and OAuth 2.0 Roadmap](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/525/)

BTW, older version of php-sdk had function `getSession`, it may be working as `GetSession` but you'll save yourself a lot of time if you'll pay attention to variables/function names... Just IMO...

Comment: Just ran the demo in PHP SDK v3.0.0  eg.
>>>>>>>>>>>
php-sdk

Login using OAuth 2.0 handled by the PHP SDK: Login with Facebook
PHP Session

You are not Connected.
Public profile of Naitik

 Naitik Shah
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

Same thing when I click on the link nothing happens